# Localize UTC time/date

Tags: javascript, react-native, momentjs

i have a timestamp which comes from server (utc). I now want to transform this timestamp to my local time.

Transform UTC:

```
2016-08-11 12:19:14
```

To local time:

```
2016-08-11 14:19:14
```

This is what i have used:

```
localizeTime = function (timeToLocalize = "2016-08-11 12:19:14") {
    return moment(timeToLocalize).locale(deviceLocale = "de").format('LLL');
};
```

I am working with react-native and moment.js

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the input time is UTC, and you don't have anything in the string to indicate such, then you need to parse it with `moment.utc` instead of just with `moment`.  You can then convert it to local time with the `local` function.

```
moment.utc("2016-08-11 12:19:14").local().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```

You don't need to involve locales (like `de`) unless you really want a locale-specific string format.  Locale has to do with language and culture, not with time zones.  `"local" != "locale"`